# Speed up reading .wav and analyse in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, audio, wav

I'm trying to read in a .wav file and maybe play around with the data eventually but I'm stuck. Just reading the file in, storing it in a struct, and writing it to another file takes a long time. Any added processing will take even longer.

I've posted my code which is fairly straight forward. I must be missing something and making the program more complicated or redundant than necessary.

```hs
import qualified Data.Char as DC
import qualified Data.Word as DW
import qualified Data.Int as DI

import qualified Data.Binary.Get as BG
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal as BLI

import qualified System.Environment as SE
import qualified System.IO as SIO

main = do
    (fstfilename:sndfilename:_) <- SE.getArgs
    fstfile <- SIO.openFile fstfilename SIO.ReadMode
    input <- BL.hGetContents fstfile

    raw_wav <- return $ BG.runGet parseWav input

    sndfile <- SIO.openFile sndfilename SIO.WriteMode
    SIO.hPutStr sndfile (show (wavData raw_wav))

data Sample = OneChannel {mono :: Integer} |
              TwoChannel {leftChannel :: Integer,
                         rightChannel :: Integer}

instance Show Sample where
    show (OneChannel m) = show m ++ " " 
    show (TwoChannel l r) = show l ++ "-" ++ show r ++ " "

data RaWavFile = RaWavFile {numChannels :: Integer,
                        sampleRate :: Integer,
                        bitsPerSample :: Integer,
                        wavData :: [Sample]}
                        deriving (Show)

parseWav :: BG.Get RaWavFile
parseWav = do
        BG.skip 22
        num_channels <- BG.getWord16le 
        sample_rate <- BG.getWord32le
        BG.skip 6
        bits_per_sample <- BG.getWord16le

        rem <- BG.getRemainingLazyByteString
        wav_data <- return $ BL.drop 8 (BL.dropWhile 
                            ((/=) (fromIntegral (DC.ord 'd') :: DW.Word8)) rem)

        nc <- return $ toInteger num_channels
        sr <- return $ toInteger sample_rate
        bps <- return $ toInteger bits_per_sample
        return $ RaWavFile nc sr bps (orgSamples nc bps wav_data)

--          numChannels bitpersample   wavData  
orgSamples :: Integer -> Integer -> BL.ByteString -> [Sample]
orgSamples nc bps BLI.Empty = [] 
orgSamples nc bps bs 
        | nc == 1 = (OneChannel (rle fb)):(orgSamples nc bps rst)
        | nc == 2 = (TwoChannel (rle fb) (rle sb)):(orgSamples nc bps rsst)
        | otherwise = error "Number of channels not 1 or 2"
            where nb = fromIntegral (bps `div` 8) :: DI.Int64
                  (fb, rst) = BL.splitAt nb bs
                  (sb, rsst) = BL.splitAt nb rst 
                  rle = toInteger . BG.runGet BG.getWord16le
```

Comment: Hmmm.. From a quick look it seems `wavData :: [Sample]` i.e reading and storing the samples in a (immutable) list could be the issue. You can try mutable arrays.

Comment: Any reason you're using lists of unpacked/nonstrict constucted Integers (I.e. the 3 least performant types for bulk data operarions)?

Comment: Indeed lists are questionable, and `Integer` is completely futile as a sample type. Where do you expect to get PCM data with resolution >64 bits from? Or even 32 bit for that matter. Use `Double` if you don't want to be bothered with quantisation or overflow issues. (Or `Float`, [but only if you've switched to unboxed arrays](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Floating_point).) – Deciding on each single sample whether it's mono or stereo is of course quite deadly for performance... it might be a good idea to simply store everything in stereo, with both channels identical for mono.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm trying to implement them now. As for why I used Integer, it's ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why it is slow.

1. You are using `Integer` for storing individual samples. `Integer` is a special type for storing arbitrary precision integers. As such, there is a good amount of overhead for every read/write of these values. Avoid at all costs. I would suggest using specifically sized types such as `Int8`/`Int16`. You should probably also parametrise over these types.
2. You are storing the samples as a tagged union of channel types. For each sample. That's a LOT of overhead. Do you really expect the number of channels to change mid-file? Probably not.
3. You are using a list to store your samples which introduces a lot of overhead when you are essentially talking about continuous streams of bytes.

## How to make it fast

1. Parametrise your type over the bit depth of the sample. I suggest directly using `Int8`/`Int16` as 8 and 16 bit tracks are the two most common formats used. You probably want to stick with them for a learning project.

   ```
   import Data.Int
   ```
2. Use [Unboxed Vectors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html) to store your data. This avoids the massive overhead of (lazy) lists and thunks, and will significantly reduce your memory consumption to boot.

   ```
   import Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
   ```
3. Don't store the number of tracks. `length $ tracks $ wavFile` will get that back any time you need it. Eliminate all usages of Integer in your code (unless you really *really* need to store a number greater than 2^64)

   ```
   data RaWavFile b = RaWavFile {
       sampleRate :: Int,
       tracks     :: [Vector b] }
       deriving (Show)
   ```
4. Use the types to guide you. `binary` is polymorphic over return types. just ask it for the type you want, and it will parse the correct number of bytes without your intervention.

   ```
   parseWav :: BL.ByteString -> BG.Get (RaWavFile b)
   wav <- parseWav input :: BG.Get (RaWavFile Int16)
   ```
5. You should only be using `BG.runGet` *once*, to run your parser against a bytestring.